# Use of 'SHALL' in contemporary English

Tags: modal-verbs

Is 'SHALL' still used in present day English, or it is outdated? And if it is still being used, then in which contexts?

Comment: **shall** is rare in AmE, except in conservative contexts like legal documents.

Answer (score 2):

**Shall** still very much gets used, more so in BrE from my experience.

> Give us a call when you get home so we know you arrived safely.
>   **I shall!**

More usually "*will*" gets used nowadays

> Give us a call when you get home so we know you arrived safely.
>   **I will!**

To me, using "**shall**" carries more weight of *obligation* and *responsibility* then "**will**" does.
Arguably, one might sound better read using "**shall**" but when not used too often.

Comment: More than this, *Shall* is a legal term which, used in a contract, imposes an obligation.  *Will* in a contract does not.